# Java object from complex XML, interested only in Child element

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

This is my XML file:

```
<Root>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Title>My title</Title>
    <More>
        <Extension>Ex</Extension>
        <Extra>Extra info</Extra>
            <Comments>
                <Comment date="2018-11-26T06:00:00+02:00">Hey, this is my comment</Comment>
                <Comment date="2017-11-26T06:00:00+02:00">Hey, this is my comment</Comment>
                <Comment date="2016-11-26T06:00:00+02:00">Hey, this is my comment</Comment>
                <Comment date="2011-11-26T06:00:00+02:00">Hey, this is my comment</Comment>
            </Comments>
    </More>
</Root>
```

I am only interested in `<Comment>` data. 
My current approach is using JaxB unmarshalling and having classes Root.java, More.java, Comments.java which contains class Comment.java. So it's kinda messy.

I have no problem doing it this way, but I would like to know if there is any method that let's you go straight for the `<Comment>` data and having only 1 class Comment.java for it?

Comment: what is the "data"?

Comment: <Comment date="2018-11-26T06:00:00+02:00">Hey, this is my comment</Comment> From here i need date and "Hey, this is my comment"

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get all the *comment* tags from the XML file, you may try out following approach,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ReadComments {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException { 
        File xml = new File("D:/data.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xml);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Comment");

        for (int i= 0; i< nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                System.out.printf("Comment : %s | Date : %s\n", node.getTextContent(), element.getAttribute("date"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Comment : Hey, this is my comment | Date : 2018-11-26T06:00:00+02:00
Comment : Hey, this is my comment | Date : 2017-11-26T06:00:00+02:00
Comment : Hey, this is my comment | Date : 2016-11-26T06:00:00+02:00
Comment : Hey, this is my comment | Date : 2011-11-26T06:00:00+02:00
```

Note that this is just an example to explain about getting details of specific tags, you will have to modify this code as per for your need.